# Redirecting output to file

Tags: linux, arch-linux, io-redirection

I am looking forward to run commands and log their output in a temporary log file to be read later on by different processes.

So, for example: `rc.d start ntpd > progress.txt`

Returns:
**`::`**`Daemon script`**`ntpd`**`does not exist or is not executable.`

I assume, that since it's an error it doesn't get redirected, but, is there a way to force redirect everything to file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only redirect `STDOUT` to `progress.txt` but errors are normally written to `STDERR`.

To redirect both `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to `progress.txt` try:

```
rc.d start ntpd &> progress.txt
```

You'll find many additional information on this topic if you search for [io-redirection](/questions/tagged/io-redirection).

Comment: `&>` is not available in all shells (e.g. older ones), so if you are ever in one of those and wonder why `&>` doesn't work, it is equivalent to the more portable `> file 2>&1`.