# Redirecting without color

Tags: linux, arch-linux, io-redirection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output)

How do I disable all color codes when redirecting to file?

I previously asked [how to redirect everything to file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47823/redirecting-output-to-file), now I want to know how to redirect without colors.

So instead of:

```
^[(B^[[m^[[1m^[[31m:: ^[(B^[[m^[[1mDaemon script ^[(B^[[m^[[1m^[[31mntpd^[(B^[[m^[[1m does not exist or is not executable.^[(B^[[m
```

I'm looking forward to achieve plain:

`:: Daemon script ntpd does not exist or is not executable.`

#### Update:

Looking at jw013 provided link, I tried the `sed` approach:

`rc.d restart ntpd | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" &> progress.txt`

But it didn't even redirect, and simply displayed the colored output to the console.

#### Update 2:

After user1146332 comment, in order to pipe STDERR, I have to pipe with `|&`.

`rc.d restart ntpd | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" &> progress.txt`

Resulted in:

`^[(B:: ^[(BDaemon script ^[(Bntpd^[(B does not exist or is not executable.^[(B`

It's tidier, but still some codes remain. But that `sed` RegExp is too hard for me to decypher.

Comment: [possibly related SF question](http://serverfault.com/q/71285/90475)

Comment: related to **Upadte**: replace first `|` by `|&`. Same problem here, that with `|` only `STDOUT` is piped...

Comment: Many programs only use colors when their output is a terminal, not when it's a pipe. If your program always outputs colors, see [Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14684)

Comment: @Gilles, your script owns. It did it, now, would you mind providing it as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 4):

Since you're running arch linux, you could export USECOLOR variable,

```
%> export USECOLOR="no"  # color-less
%> /etc/rc.d/ntpd stop
```

And the sed trick to strip off colors,

`rc.d stop ntpd | sed -r "s:\x1B\[[0-9;]*[mK]::g"`

But this can't handle backspaces generated from rc.d

Comment: Why running `/etc/rc.d/ntpd stop` returns without colors when `USECOLOR="no"`, but `rc.d stop ntpd` returns with them?

Answer (score 2):

One easy probably more universal method is to change the TERM variable to that does not support colors like maybe 'vt100'?

Answer (score 1):

Wrote this on-the-fly, not sure about the format of your color codes but maybe give it a try:

`command | awk '{gsub(/\^[^Bm]*[Bm]/,"")}1'`

Comment: It only did repositioning of some brackets.