# What does ">" do vs ">>"?

Tags: linux, ls, command

I am currently doing preparation for my GCSE computing controlled assessment on Linux. I type `ls > list` and `ls >> list` into the command line, but it does not do anything. I have googled it but I can't find what it exactly does.

What does:

```
ls > list
```

and

```
ls >> list
```

do?

Comment: [Redirecting output to file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47823/redirecting-output-to-file)

Answer (score 51):

Both redirect stdout to file.

```
ls > list
```

If the file exists it'll be replaced.

```
ls >> list
```

If the file does not exist it'll be created. If it exists, it'll be appended to the end of the file.

Find out more: [IO Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Comment: This should be accepted.

Answer (score 23):

This:

```
ls > list
```

means redirect the output from the `ls` command to **create** a new file called `list`.  If the file already exists, **replace** it.

Whereas

```
ls >> list
```

means redirect the output from the `ls` command and **append** it to the file called `list`  If the file doesn't exist then **create** it.

---

Typically `>` is used when wiping out an existing file is ok.  This often means that outputs continually overwrites a file based on the latest current state of things.  For instance every time you test a program you might over-write the previous test output.

Typically `>>` is used for items such as logging events, parsing or other data processing where data is created or transformed piece by piece into a new form

Answer (score 1):

Both commands redirect output of `ls` command to file with name `list`. `>` will create/replace the output file with name `list`. `>>` will create (if file `list` not exists already) or append the file `list`. Can see the contents of file `list` using `cat list`.